# Add one parameter to a Symfony firewall based on current host

Tags: php, security, symfony, basic-authentication

Before deploying my website (running on Symfony 2.7) on the production server, I do it on a development server (but in `prod` environment too). As I don't want anybody to see it, I would like to secure it with a simple HTTP Basic Authentication.

I've seen that I can add a [host parameter](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-restrict-security-firewalls-to-specific-hosts) to a firewall so that it only applies when the site is run on a given host. It looks like this could help me here, but as I understand it I would have to duplicate my firewall, which is not so interesting (DRY):

```
firewalls:
    main:
        host: www\.mysite\.com
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            // ...
        logout:
            // ...
        anonymous: true
        remember_me:
            key: %secret%

    main_dev:
        host: dev\.mysite\.com
        http_basic: true
        // paste here the exact same content as in `main`
```

Is there a solution that doesn't involve maintaining two identical firewalls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose to use two different configuration files, see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/configuration_organization.html

So having a security.yml and a security_dev.yml -> all your stages use security.yml and only in dev you have your additional/different parameter loaded.

Comment: I forgot to mention that on both servers the site runs in `prod` environment. Sorry about that. I edited my question.

Comment: but still you could create a config environment for prod1 or prod2 e.g., see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/environments.html